# A partition problem.

Tags: co.combinatorics

Denote by  $\omega_{d,n}(N)$ the number non-negative integer solutions of the following system of equations: 
 \begin{gather*}
  \alpha_1+2 \alpha_2+\cdots+d \alpha_d=N,
\end{gather*}
$$
 \alpha_0+\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\cdots+\alpha_d=n. $$

The  following Proposition is a well-known simple combinatorial fact, see for example G.Andrews, The Theory of Partitions, Theorem 1.4.

**Proposition.** $\omega_{d,n}(N)=\omega_{n,d}(N).$

I am   interested in a generalisation of the above in the following direction.  For given integer $n,d,N_1,N_2$ consider  the system of equations for a set of $\dfrac{(d+1)(d+2)}{2}$ variables  $\alpha_{i,j},$ $ 0 \leq i+j \leq d :$

$$
  \displaystyle \sum_{0\leq i+j \leq d}i \alpha_{i,j}=N_1,
$$
$$
  \displaystyle \sum_{0\leq i+j \leq d}j \alpha_{i,j}=N_2,$$
$$
   \displaystyle \sum_{0\leq i+j \leq d} \alpha_{i,j}=n,
$$
and denotes by  $\omega_{d,n}(N_1,N_2)$ the number non-negative integer solutions of the  system.

In generally  $\omega_{d,n}(N_1,N_1)\neq \omega_{n,d}(N_1,N_2).$

**Question.** 1) For  what  $n,d,N_1,N_2$  we  have $\omega_{d,n}(N_1,N_2)= \omega_{n,d}(N_1,N_2)?$

2) Find a recurrence  relation which involves both  $\omega_{d,n}(N_1,N_2)$ and $ \omega_{n,d}(N_1,N_2).$

Comment: Conjectural answer to question 1: $\omega_{d,n}(N_1,N_2)= \omega_{n,d}(N_1,N_2)$ iff $\min(N_1 + N_2 -  \min(d,n), N_1, N_2) \leq 1$ or $\max(N_1 + N_2, N_1 + \min(d,n), N_2 + \min(d,n)) \geq dn - 1$ or $n = d$.